# Changes made to my Assets.xcassets folder are not being picked up when I re-run my application?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

## Overview:

Currently working with **Arkit 2.0** running on **Xcode:11.2.1**.

Im trying to extend an existing project of mine to have more **AR Reference Images**. It's a very simple application that scans images and overlays a .mp4 video over the top of it.

At the moment the application works fine for 1 of my images. Whenever I go to add more images as reference images, no changes are being picked up.

I can even remove my existing Reference Image (So no images exist at all in the project). Re Run the app and the app still picks up the original working reference image up. It's as if no changes are being picked up in that folder.  Any changes made to my existing code base is picked up just fine.

### My Issue:

Any changes I make to my Assets.xcassets folder (i.e. add a new AR Reference Image for image tracking) are not being picked up when I go to rerun the app.

### What I have done to try and fix it:

I have tried to **remove** the current **Assets.cassets** folder from Build Phase > Copy Bundle Resource.  Then **re adding the folder**, but no still no changes are being picked up.

### The exception being thrown:

After re adding the folder, cleaning my build and running the app again the application freezes outputting the following error:

```
2019-11-28 15:59:35.265955+0100 Image TrackAR[15721:1026007] [framework] CoreUI: RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: 'com.{mybundleid}' 2019-11-28 15:59:35.266144+0100 Image TrackAR[15721:1026007] [framework] CoreUI: RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: 'com.{mybundleid}' 2019-11-28 15:59:35.266613+0100 Image TrackAR[15721:1026007] [General] Error while opening catalog named "Assets" in bundle "(null)": Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: com.sambowen" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=RunTimeThemeRefForBundleIdentifierAndName() couldn't find Assets.car in bundle with identifier: com.{mybundleid}
```

I really can't understand whats going wrong, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you clear the DerivedData cache?

Comment: Have just tried deleting the DerivedData cache and still no change. Still throwing the same error.

Comment: I was afraid of that. But my impression is that this console message is not all that important. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912288/how-to-fix-warning-coreui-runtimethemerefforbundleidentifierandname-couldnt